# Формат csv файла

Tags: excel, vba, csv

Добрый день. Написал макрос, который создает структурированную таблицу на отдельном листе, а потом ее сохраняет в новый файл с csv расширением.

Проблема в том, что на работе этот файл создается с разделителями в виде запятых(винда чешская), а надо чтобы разделить был точка с запятой.

p.s. дома на английской винде все нормально.

Можно это как-то исправить?

Comment: Поменять разделитель в настройках локали Windows или в настройках Excel не вариант? (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other/how-do-i-change-the-system-separator-delimiter-to/9f8d5f2c-940f-4418-b952-bfeac867c03e?auth=1)

Comment: поменял, но изменений никаких нет.

Comment: убрал значения local:=true и заработало. спасибо!